# Sometimes, images do not load

Tags: image, performance, ftp, server, loading

Upon loading my site (https://ameersavage.com), certain images do not load in Chrome. Upon reloading the page, the results vary. Rarely does everything load properly in Chrome. This only started happening once I uploaded the site to the server.

When I uploaded the site using the server's online cPanel, none of the assets appeared until I started fiddling with each individual file's permission. I then tried uploading the site using FTP (Transmit) which produced far better results, but still certain assets sometimes do not always show up once the page loads.

Do you think this is a reflection of poor server performance? I wanted to get a second opinion before I subscribe to a new server provider (any recommendations?).

Comment: It looks like you have a number of console errors that should be resolved. Also, make use of tools like [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) and [Google Page Insights.](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Here is the GTmetrix report on your site: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/savagedesign.divasangels.com/lGr8Ck4R

Comment: Thanks for the reply. None of these errors seem to be directly related to performance issues with the images that load inconsistently.